# ¿Cómo filtrar palabras con tíldes en una búsqueda usando Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Buen día, estoy utilizando Mat-Autocomplete para realizar un filtro de búsqueda en un input y quisiera saber cómo podría ignorar los caracteres con tilde.

Mí código .TS es el siguiente:

```
this.filteredUserServices = this.saloonServiceControl.valueChanges
                .pipe(
                    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
                    startWith<string | ISaloonServiceOfUser>(''),
                    filter(service => typeof service === 'string'),
                    map((service: string) => this._filterService(service)));

private _filterService(value: string): ISaloonServiceOfUser[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.listServices.filter(option => option.short_name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}
```

Y en el HTML:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let service of filteredUserServices | async" [value]="service">
        {{ service?.short_name }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar la siguente función que toma como parámetro una cadena y reeemplaza todos los acentos por sus vocales sin acento:

```
filtrar_acentos(input){

            var acentos = "ÃÀÁÄÂÈÉËÊÌÍÏÎÒÓÖÔÙÚÜÛãàáäâèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûÑñÇç";
            var original = "AAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUUaaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunncc";
            for (var i = 0; i < acentos.length; i++) {
                input = input.replace(acentos.charAt(i), original.charAt(i)).toLowerCase();
            };
            return input;
       }
```

Y luego usarla en el filtro:

```
 return this.listServices.filter(option => filtrar_acentos(option.short_name.toLowerCase()).includes(filterValue));
```